# SSD won't show up in Windows installer

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I am experiencing anissue when installing Windows 7 64-bit on a clean 240GB SSD. My motherboard is a GA-MA785GMT-UD2H, BIOS detects the SATA drive and Windows 7 does detect the drive when booting off my old HDD.  I know the drive is good.

Updated the Firmware on the SSD

Updated the motherboard BIOS firmware

I have enabled SATA and using AHCI

Connected my SSD to sata port 0 on the mortherboard

Disconnected all other HDD

Downloaded the Windows 7 64-bite Sata AHCI drivers from Gigabyte website and installed on thumb drive

I click on load drivers, browse to the thumb drive, select the drive and click OK.

Windows 7 still does not find the SSD drive.

Comment: Similar question.  http://superuser.com/questions/323578/ssd-drive-is-not-recognized-while-installing-windows?rq=1